# JCrop cropping the wrong area

Tags: php, jcrop

I need some help with my implementation of JCrop.  I tried to follow the manual but whenever I select an area, it's not actually selecting what I have selected.  Instead it's taking some area outside my selection.  Sometimes, it's taking the area almost properly (I am thinking because of the photo size) but mostly it's taking wrong area.  Please help.  Here's my code:

Note $photo is the uploaded image. It's being uploaded properly so no issue on that.

The 120 x 120 is the pixels I want to save the uploaded pictures to so as to save storage space.  Also, here's the css of the `<img>` element where I display the image for cropping:

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
```

Here's my php code:

```
$twidth = 120;
$theight = 120;
$quality = 90;
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($photo);
$dst = ImageCreateTrueColor($twidth, $theight);
$x = $_POST['x'];
$y = $_POST['y'];
$w = $_POST['w'];
$h = $_POST['h'];
imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, $x, $y, $twidth, $theight, $w, $h);
imagejpeg($dst, $photo, $quality);
```

Comment: I solved it already.  I resampled the image on when i first upload it, so the jcrop will work on the new resampled image already, not from the original image.  The image size really affects the jcropping.  While I made the image fit my page, the jcrop is actually cropping the original image which is larger; thus it's not cropping properly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are resizing the image box with css. This is creating difficulties for the script to find the correct area. 
Instead you should limit the box width/height with Jcrop function as below:

```
$('#cropbox').Jcrop({
        boxWidth: 480,   //Maximum width you want for your bigger images
        boxHeight: 480,  //Maximum Height for your bigger images
...
});
```

If you use this Jcrop setting it would take the wanted area, otherwise it is not working as expected.

Best wishes